# Use tables imported in another SSAS Tabular project in the same solution

Tags: visual-studio, ssas-tabular

I have the following solution containing 2 SSAS Tabular projects like below :

[image]

The first `Model.bim` contains FCT_Objectif_Banque_Prototype :

- DimDate
- DimBanque
- FCT_Objectif_Banque

The relationship is one to many from each dimension to the fact table.

The second `Model.bim` contains FCT_Objectif_Delegue_Prototype :

- DimDate
- DimDelegue
- FCT_Objectif_Delegue

The relationship is one to many from each dimension to the fact table.

I am importing the same `DimDate` twice, I thought about having the `DimDate` in a separate project
but how can I establish a relationship between a fact table and a dimension belonging each one to a separate project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I establish a relationship between a fact table and a dimension belonging each one to a separate project?

You can't.  Each project is self-contained.  There's a (preview) feature for Power BI that allows you to combine data from multiple models called [DirectQuery for Power BI datasets and Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services), but it's not available (or AFAIK planned) for SSAS.

Even if it were possible, dimension tables are typically not very large, so importing them in multiple models is the preferred solution.